# I'd like to reference a button status within a script

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I reference my menu button from my script? When I click the button after implementation, it doesn't seem to hold true... Thank you for your help! The problem here is specifically directed towards the if statement in the bottom script where it states if(data_type ==1){ do something}.

```
var data_type = 0;

function data() {

        data_type = 1;
    }

///menu-button///
<li id="menu" onclick="data()" style="max-width:82px">
            <a href="#" id="m7"> DATA </a>
</li>
<script>
document.write('<div id="div2" class="wrapper">');
document.write('<ul id="Grid">');

for (var i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
    var ch = "";
    if (i%3==0) { ch="E"; } else if (i%3==1) { ch="C"; } else { ch="W"; }
    document.write('<li id="mE'+ i + '" class="mix ' + sortSettings[i][0] + ' ' + i
                        + '" onclick="imgClicked(' + i + ')" > <div class="content"> <div><img class="bImg" id="imgI' + i
                        + '" src="ico1.jpg" width="145" height="213"></div> <div id="menu"> <img id="gI' + i + '" src="ico1.jpg" width="35" height="35" style="float:left"></div>'
                        + '<div id="descNum">' + (Math.floor(i/3)+1) + ch + '</div>'
                        + '<div id="desc">' + allSettings[i][1] + '</div>'
                        + '<div id="desc">' + allSettings[i][2] + '</div>'
                        + '<div id="desc">' + allSettings[i][0] +' '+ allSettings[i][3] + '</div></div></li>');
}

for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var add = "";
        if(data_type == 1){
            if (j==0) {
                add="E";
                $("#imgI" + ((i*3)+j)).attr("src", "Beds/20160530/" + (i+1) + add + "(1).JPG");
            } else if (j==1) {
                add="C";
                $("#imgI" + ((i*3)+j)).attr("src", "Beds/20160530/" + (i+1) + add + "(1).JPG");
            } else if (j==2) {
                add="W";
                $("#imgI" + ((i*3)+j)).attr("src", "Beds/20160530/" + (i+1) + add + "(1).JPG");
            }
        }


        else{
            if (j==0) {
                add="E";
                $("#imgI" + ((i*3)+j)).attr("src", "Beds/20160530/" + (i+1) + add + ".JPG");
            } else if (j==1) {
                add="C";
                $("#imgI" + ((i*3)+j)).attr("src", "Beds/20160530/" + (i+1) + add + ".JPG");
            } else if (j==2) {
                add="W";
                $("#imgI" + ((i*3)+j)).attr("src", "Beds/20160530/" + (i+1) + add + ".JPG");
            }
        }

    }
}

document.write('<li class="gap"></li>');
document.write('</ul>');
document.write('</div>');
</script>
```

Comment: Can you put your code divide in HTML, JS with all the global vars that you use?

Comment: I see uses of jQuery, which you haven't set the `.ready()` handler for yet. Also, people advise against `document.write()` because it will overwrite all HTML if the document was loaded.